# Spring batch running steps in parallel

Tags: spring-batch

Step 1- Tasklet : I am reading a db table Employee that has EmpId, EmpName, EmpAddress, it return 8 rows (can change). I have set the List in jobExecutionContext.
Starting step 2:
i) for the returned employee list, I need to execute a query by giving empId for every record present in the list.
ii) Result of that query is written into a file.
iii) Copy that file to a different server
iv) Send email with stats of the file.

Step i) to iv) needs to be performed for every employee returned by first query in parallel. e.g. if there are 8 employees then step i) to iv) should be executed in parallel for all the 8 emp Id.
Can someone please guide me on this? What type of xml step configuration should be used?

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using `tasklet` attributes: `task-executor` and `throttle-limit`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep